# How to show a web content (graph) using `Julia` in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, julia

Consider the following `Python` code to show the content of a URL in Jupyter Notebook (it is a graph from [FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org))

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
url = 'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/graph-landing.php?g=BOLN&width=420&height=320'
IFrame(src=url, width=450, height=330)
```

I want to achieve the same result using `Julia` in Jupyter Notebook. I tried [IJuliaPortrayals](https://github.com/jbn/IJuliaPortrayals.jl), but I guess it is not compatible with the latest `Julia`. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WebIO.jl for this.

```
using WebIO
node(:iframe; src=url, width=420, height=320)
```

[image]

Note that installation of support for Jupyter extension is required for WebIO to work. This can be done with code below:

```
using Conda
Conda.pip_interop(true)
Conda.pip("install", "webio_jupyter_extension")
```